# Gis data source

Tags: database, gis

can anyone suggest if there's any information source from where I can know about the infrastructure, buildings, roads, pipelines, parks etc existing at some point back in time. Like what things existed in the 1970s , 1950s etc. Are there such data repositories existing for anywhere(city or a county etc) . Or any organisation recording information about the time the buildings, homes etc were built so I can extract the info from there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my GIS certificate program we used Sanborn maps to perform digitization of features like roads and buildings which existed historically in the US.

https://www.loc.gov/collections/sanborn-maps/about-this-collection/

> The Sanborn map collection consists of a uniform series of large-scale maps, dating from 1867 to the present and depicting the commercial, industrial, and residential sections of some twelve thousand cities and towns in the United States, Canada, and Mexico.

edit:

In the future posting on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ would be better.

edit:

I mentioned Sanborn maps specifically because they provide a good historical view, and the poster mentioned 1950s - 1970s, etc. Since the Sanborn maps do not seem suitable for the requirement, I would recommend starting with government data portals, such as http://data.gov.uk and https://www.data.gov/ (US), industry portals such http://opendata.arcgis.com/, as well as check out crowd-sourced open data initiatives such as https://www.openstreetmap.org.

Comment: Thanks for your answer a lot, and for making me aware of gisstackexchange, but those sources are usually available in the form of paper maps, non digital scanned images, digitization of those maps hasnt been done (on large scale) as they now offer no use i suppose.

Comment: Please upvote my answer rather than thanking me. Upvoting is the best way to say thanks on SO. Good luck in your search.